# GitLab: How to display Wiki as start page instead of readme?

Tags: gitlab

I want to have the start page of the wiki of a project in GitLab as general start page for the project. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently possible. The only views available which you can find in /profile/preferences are activity and readme.

Comment: Apparently, this is already an existing feature request: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/9037822-add-the-option-to-set-the-wiki-as-project-view

Comment: As gitlab deprecated the forum, the feature request can be tracked through [Allow for Wiki as default project view.](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/12922)

Comment: The issue posted by @Murmel was moved and is now found here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14995

Answer (score 2):

This is possible because there's a [bug in gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21603) does exactly what you want, but only

- for **logged in** users accessing
- a **public wiki-only** project

So i guess „It's not a bug, it's a feature" ;)

---

### Update

Having checked the [example repository](https://gitlab.com/ryancey/issue-wikiproject) in the above linked issue, what you're asking for seems to be the default behaviour on gitlab.com now for wiki-only projects (which means you have to go into the settings and disable the repository feature).

I just verified that by setting up a fresh wiki-only project and it shows empty wiki page as homepage which was [introduced in 12.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2018/11/22/gitlab-11-5-released/#empty-state-for-wiki-only-projects).